Installation of libc6 stuck in WSL Kali Linux
I recently shifted WSL since I already turned it for Docker from using VM due to space in my drive. I installed Kali Linux and ubuntu in WSL.
Ubuntu worked perfectly without a hitch but when i upgrade my Kali Linux it got struck in installing libc6 I tried several option from Stack Overflow from previous question on ubuntu but none of them worked for me. I am using Windows 11 and download Kali Linux using both store and wsl --install.
sudo apt install libc6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libc6 is already the newest version (2.37-15).
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc-bin libc-l10n locales-all
Recommended packages:
  manpages
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc-bin libc-l10n locales-all
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 45 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/12.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.37-15) ...

Progress: [  7%] [############...............................................................................................................................................................................]


Well don't have much to say about this, but i got it solved using the following commands:
sudo mv /usr/sbin/telinit /usr/sbin/telinit.bak 
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/true /usr/sbin/telinit

I don't know how this solved my problem. But it really worked for me. I tried searching in online blogs rather than asking AI; I previously tried AI for code generation but it leave me a bitter taste while I was learning something new to me. Should have used AI before.
